# How to interact with a shell in scripts

Tags: python, shell

I want to interact with scripts engine just like javascript or python shell,and then provide services for browsers.It's just allow using shell in web page.(I am not good at English:)
  The main problem is fr.readline could not read any data from the read end craeted by os.pipe().I think the reason is the child process open this file descriptor.It recalls me of the error--'Resources temporarilly unvaliable'.
Because when i use os.fdopen to create a file association to the write end of pipe,the read end also couldn't recv data only if i haven't close write file,and that's why i use os.write to send data to child process.

```
import os
import sys
from select import select
from socket import *

p1=os.pipe()
p2=os.pipe()
pid=os.fork()
if pid==0:
    os.close(p1[0])
    os.close(p2[1])
    os.dup2(p1[0],0)    # redirect input and output of this python shell
    os.dup2(p2[1],1)
    os.execvp('python',['python'])
else:
    os.close(p1[0])
    os.close(p2[1])
    fr=os.fdopen(p2[0])
    server=socket()
    server.bind(('0.0.0.0',42800))
    server.listen(1)
    while True:
        client,addr=server.accept()
        while True:
            if select([fr],[],[],1)[0]:
                msg=fr.readline()
                msg=client.recv(1024)
                print msg
                os.write(p1[1],msg)
                while not select([fr],[],[],1)[0]:
                    continue
                rep=fr.readline()
                client.send(rep)
                while not select([fr],[],[])[0]:
                    client.send(fr.readline())
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problems you are having?  "doesn't work good" is not very helpful.

Comment: e,this is the code written by myself,i'am sorry abount that i couldn't express my idea,and thanks for your advise.I'am really not good in English.

Comment: the problem is after i call os.write to send msg to chilld process,i could not read data with fr.readline,it will block.